# Does Indefinite article convey a count singular number of a noun?

Tags: grammar

Dear native speakers,

Can indefinite article «a» in some cases convey the meaning of singularity, indicating a singular number?

I have always thought it does.

e.g.: A book is lying on the table.

Does it imply that an unknown book (first mention) is lying on the table or one book is lying on the table?

In other words, if i want to show singularity of a noun, can i use article -a instead of one?

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit and provide examples where "a" is not referring to a singular number. In other words, you need to provide more detail than is currently shown.

Comment: Mari-Lou A, thank you! I have corrected my question.

Comment: Use of the indefinite article doesn't just "imply" that the referent is a *singular* noun - it ***entails*** the noun being singular (something which is ***implied*** might feasibly not be true in any given case; if it's ***entailed***, it must ***always*** be true). If the noun is plural we have to either use a different determiner such as ***some***, or use the "zero article": ***Books are on the table***.

Comment: FumbleFingers, thank you for your comment, for your help. It is clear now for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sentence “A book is lying on the table”,  "**a** book" could suggest that there is only one book in the room, and it is currently on a table. That the speaker does not know the title of the book is not of importance, the number of books on the table is one. If the speaker knew the title, they might say

> "Les Miserables" **is** on the table.

Quite often the indefinite article "a" means one of any number, e.g.;
"***An*** irishman, ***an*** Italian, and ***a*** German walk into ***a*** bar.”

Comment: Mari-Lou A, Thank you! it answers my question))) Have a good day!

Comment: This answer could be improved by more forcefully stating: Yes, the indefinite article 'a'* *always* means one. There is no case in which 'a' means more than one.

Comment: a101010, Thank you ! that was a great help!